# Migrating from Cordova File Transfer using blobs feasible?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

It looks like cordova file transfer plugin has been retired (I'm using cordova 7.1 and cordova-file-plugin v6.0.1) and the file-transfer plugin now recommends using the XHR XMLHttpRequest to obtain the data from a remote server to save locally.

All the examples seem to show downloading data which is either a PNG or a text file however I use it to download many file types such as images, text and binary data.

I next use FileReader to read in files from the non-backedup cloud location.  Attempting to use the XHR by simple copy/paste seems to fail so curious if anyone has a SIMPLE example of downloading a file from the internet and reading that file in on Cordova.

I simply can't believe it is as complicated as these examples make out (like writing 20 lines of code to save a simple file) so any pointers or examples for a generic download/plugin to cache for offline usage would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you coding in straight HTML/JS, or are you using a framework like Angular/React?  The code to make this type of request could differ quite a bit.  For example, Angular has an HttpClient module to abstract some of the XHR things away.

Comment: Only using straight html/js within the cordova environment on iOS/Android.